# If you're born on an airplane, do you get free flights for life?

Tags: aviation, marketing, pregnancy

It's a common myth that if you're born on an airplane, or mid-flight, you get free flights for life from whatever company is running the flight.

[Example of a claim](http://www.gadling.com/2009/10/23/want-a-lifetime-of-free-flights-give-birth-on-board/) - just pertaining to one company, but the article makes it seem common place.

Is this true, in general?

Comment: anecdotally - of two babies born on my dad's plane when he flew for a Scottish airline, neither have free flights for life. It wasn't even considered.

Comment: I remember it being mentioned in some show on Discovery Channel or the like about air planes - you don't get free flights for life.

Comment: However if you are born in other unusual places you might get [other benefits](http://www.cbc.ca/news/offbeat/story/2012/05/09/wdr-tim-hortons-baby-free-timbits.html).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to **[Snopes](http://www.snopes.com/pregnant/airbaby.asp)** the answer is **NO**:

> [image: Snopes]

Barbara Mikkelson (who has contacted several airlines to get to the bottom of this) speculates:

> ... the origin of the "lifetime pass" legend came about as a fanciful explanation for why some airlines refuse passage to expectant women.

---

And there are indeed special regulations for pregnant women, e.g.

> **[British Airways](http://www.britishairways.com/health/docs/before/airtravel_guide.pdf)**
>
> Whilst pregnancy is not a “medical condition”, flying whilst pregnant
> is a frequently raised topic.
>
> Normally pregnancy is a happy event for
> all concerned but **delivery in flight it is not without risks to the
> mother and baby. For this reason British Airways, along with many
> airlines, refuses to carry women in the latter stages of pregnancy,
> typically after 36 weeks for single pregnancies, 32 weeks for
> multiple.**

> **[Civil Aviation Authority](http://www.caa.co.uk/docs/923/Fitness_To_Fly_-_Dec_2011.pdf)**
>
> Delivery in flight, or diversion in flight to a location that may not
> have high quality obstetric services, is undesirable.
>
> For this reason,
> **most airlines do not allow travel after 36 weeks for a single
> pregnancy and after 32 weeks for a multiple pregnancy.**

> **[Korean Airlines](http://www.koreanair.com/local/kr/gd/eng/cs/sn/eng_cs_sn_pg.jsp)**
>
> [image: Pregnancy]

---

**[IATA](http://www.iata.org/Pages/default.aspx)** ([International Air Transport Association](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Air_Transport_Association)), which represents some 240 airlines, has a 398 pages thick [Standard's Manual](http://www.iata.org/ps/certification/iosa/Documents/IOSAStandardsManualEd4.pdf) (from December 2011), but there is no mention of free flights for new-borns.

[IATA Medical Guidelines](http://www.iata.org/whatwedo/safety_security/safety/health/Documents/medical-manual-jan2011.pdf) for pregnancy:

> [image: Pregnancy]

I also browsed through several airline's webpages and while they all do mention special rules for pregnant women, neither says anything about a "bonus" when you deliver in-flight.

On the contrary some airlines even refuse to carry "highly" pregnant women (see above).

---

But, as the link in the question shows, reported cases do exist:

> A baby boy who made a surprise arrival on board an AirAsia flight this
> week will be given free flights for life with the budget carrier, as
> will his mother.
>
> ...
>
> "***To celebrate this momentous occasion, we
> decided to present both mother and child with free flights for life***,"
> said AirAsia's director of operations Moses Devanayagam.
>
> [[Source](http://www.abs-cbnnews.com/lifestyle/10/23/09/lifetime-free-flights-baby-born-plane)]

---

Comment: I wonder the AirAsia case is a case of a self-fufilling myth - something that was originally false, but since became true because it was widely known.